# Firebase Installations Service is unavailable. Please try again later

Tags: android, firebase, sdk

I use firebase cloud messaging to send push notifications in my sdk. But if I connect the sdk to an application that already uses firebase cloud messaging, then when I try to take the device's fcm token, I get an error Firebase Installations Service is unavailable. Please try again later.

Comment: It would probably help if you could add the stacktrace of the errors you are seeing and some code snippets of how you are configuring/handling token generation for Firebase.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this?